# Cannot install Kubuntu

Tags: installation, kubuntu

I have a Emachines E525 laptop and I'm trying to install Kubuntu 10.10 on it.
I've downloaded the ISO image from the website, burned it to a CD, inserted the CD into the Emachines laptop and when I boot from it I just get:

```
ISOLINUX 4.01 debian-20100714 ETCD Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al
```

And that is all. It just hangs here. No menu to install it no nothing. The CD is working fine on my other laptop.

Any ideas?

**LE:**

No message at all. Black screen showing at the top of the screen what i typed above.
Specs:

- Intel Celeron 2.2GHz
- 3GB DDR2
- 250GB HDD
- Mobile Intel GL40 Express Chipset

**LE2:**
Just tried a old CD with Ubuntu 8.04 and this boots, :( so is this related just to Kubuntu? don't both use the same boot loader? or maybe 10.10 uses a newer version of the boot loader that has issues...?

Comment: A little more detail would be appreciated. do you get any messages at all. what are the specs of your machine?

Comment: What graphics card you have..?

Comment: Please try Ubuntu 10.04 and report if that fails to boot.

Comment: if you can boot from USB on this system, would it be possible for you to test a usb boot? I've seen this happen on some systems, no explanation (it's just odd), but sometimes a USB boot works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

Answer (score 1):

If the processor is Intel Celeron, you have to make sure that ubuntu installer is 32 bit.