# error: no such partition (duplicate, but none of the others helped, unless I missed one)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, restore

Hi I have a Sony Vaio VPCEJ with Windows 7 as the primary OS. I installed Ubuntu, as dual boot, a year ago for school because I had a sudden interest in programming and thought it would be fun to learn how to use it. Unfortunately I've stopped using it and being "smart" I deleted the partitions that were blank. Now when I start my laptop I get:
error: no such partition.
grub rescue

The only command that works here is "ls" and I checked each of the options that were written ("ls (hs0,y") to see what I can do, but that amounted to nothing and other then that I have no idea what I can do there.

When I set up Ubuntu Boot Drive on a USB (like lili usb creator or universal usb installer) this shows up:
SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H: Peter Anvin et al

If I try F10, F8, or alt+f8/f10 I only get a blank screen. It won't let me Factory reset or access the menus altogether.

Tomorrow, I am gonna try to borrow a friends Windows 7 CD to try to boot it that way.

If there is any help you can give me, it would truly be appreciated!

Comment: For fixing the problem in SYSLINUX, see [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

Answer (score 2):

Get a windows 7 DVD or USB-drive. Boot from it and select Repair.Select Use Recovery tools
And from last click on command prompt And type these commands

```
 Bootrec/FixMBR

 Bootrec/RebuildBCD
```

This will restore your Windows boot-loader and replace grub..