# SYSLINUX 4.04 2010-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2011 H. Peter Anvin et al

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb, wubi

When I boot Ubuntu from my USB Live I get:

```
SYSLINUX 4.04 2011-04-18 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2011 H. Peter Anvin et al
```

Burned with LiLo, When I burn with UNETbootin I get:

```
SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2011 H. Peter Anvin et al
```

I have a 8GB SanDisk Cruzer Edge...

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message?rq=1

Comment: None of the similar errors seemed to help

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error as Lucas Smith with ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso burned with Startup Disk Creator (usb-creator-gtk) on a Memorex 4GB Swivel repartitioned and reformatted as FAT32 (no U3 folder exists.) I have seen other startup disk issues indicating Syslinux version incompatibilities. I'll wait and watch for further developments.

Comment: I forgot to finish the error line. Mine ends with "Boot error" and no other information.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a fix for the SanDisk users. It lies with the U3 folder. That prevents startup. Try to delete it and start it up that way!