# booting off a usb drive

Tags: installation, 13.04, usb

once i click the usb drive to boot off of it says 
"SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-13 Copyright (C) 1994-1012 H. Peter Anvin et al" 
the rest of the screen is black and i have no idea what to do. can anyone help me?

Comment: Related: [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total newb at this so my answer may be of no value, but here's what I did to boot from usb:
 Download an iso. file of whatever distro you want.  download linux pendrive or a similar usb installer.  using pendrive, select your downloaded iso file to make bootable on your usb key.  Make sure your computer is set to boot from usb first, then reset and boot. The rest should be self explanatory.  Good luck getting wifi connectivity though.  Hope that helps.