# delete xp without removing ubunutu

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

I have installed ubuntu 13.04 over Windows xp through wubi.exe because i have tried installing ubuntu through usb but it seems like my laptop usb is not supporting it though it shows 
SYSLINUX.........

in boot screen and hangs up that's why i quit usb installation and tried wubi.exe.

After installing Ubuntu 13.04 through wubi it seems like xp and ubuntu both are installed in same partition, thats a problem for me...

I want to delete xp without removing ubunutu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you need to do a proper install.

There's no simple way to convert a wubi install to a real one either, so you're going to need to overcome whatever the problem is that's stopping you boot to USB. There are a few suggestions here:

- [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)