# Ubuntu WILL NOT boot, no matter what i do. Need help!

Tags: 13.10

Ubuntu is not booting from a USB on my Acer V3-571G.

I have tried using a 8GB Sandisk Cruzer memory stick, formatted as FAT32, and this returned a black screen with the 'Syslinux: Peter Anvin et al' error. I used Unetbootin to create the memory stick.

This error always used to happen on my little Acer D250 netbook, and the reason was because the memory stick needed to be formatted as FAT, and not FAT32.

I formatted the memory stick as FAT and made another USB in Unetbootin. This time i was using my 4GB TDK USB drive. The Unetbootin menu came up but it froze when i clicked any of the boot options. Even if i left it past the boot timeout, it would still freeze.

I then used Lili USB creator instead, again with the TDK memory stick, but this doesn't work either. I get to the purple Ubuntu screen with the keyboard symbol and the man symbol, and then it goes onto a black screen with a blinking cursor.

The laptop is in Legacy boot mode with secure boot disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This question may also help: [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

Answer (score 0):

What if you create your Ubuntu LiveUSB using this: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

I've personally had problems with UnetBootin...

Universal USB Installer automatically formats your USB...